# How to configure confluent kafka rest serializer?

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Is it possible to change confluent kafka-rest serializer? I want to swap the confluent avro serializer to my customized serializer, but I checked inside producer-pool(https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafkarest/ProducerPool.java).

When building buildAvroProducer it ask for KafkaAvroSerializer, which is a confluent lib. So it seems not possible to customize it without code changes(like simply swap jar in classpath or sth)
Not sure whether this requirement is fair or not, and wondering whether it is on the road map or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, this is not currently possible. The set of serializers are hard coded to map to a set of content types. You would need to make changes to the code to support alternative serializers.

Comment: can you also help the question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40644085/confluent-schema-registry-2-0-1-version-with-ssl-configuration