# Confluent schema-registry 2.0.1 version with SSL configuration

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I need to use confluent schema-registry to connect to 0.9 kafka. But for schema-registry 2.0.1 version I didn't see SSL configuration available. Is there a way to enable ssl for schema-registry and kafka-rest to talk to 0.9 kafka?

Answer (score 1):

That functionality was only added as of the 3.0 release line. If you want support for 0.9/2.0 releases, you could try either a) taking a 3.0 release and reducing the Kafka dependency to 0.9 versions (this *might* work, but I think there were other unrelated changes that might require additional changes), or b) backport the SSL changes to a 2.0 version (although I can't be sure off the top of my head whether this version supports everything required to enable security support).

Note that if you follow the [upgrade docs](http://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/upgrade.html#upgrade-all-kafka-brokers), upgrading brokers to enable use of newer client versions is generally relatively painless these days.